# View rewrited URL in apache

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

I am getting some bugs hosting an application. The application uses rewrite rules. I did all tests possible and ensured that mod_rewrite is enabled in apache and the .htaccess file is being considered. I only want to visualize the URLs that is being genereted after considering the rewrite rule to continue the debug.

So my question is, given a .htaccess file with mod_rewrite turn on and rewrite rules defined in it, is it possible to view the final URL that is generated after considering the the rewrite rules ?

Comment: You want to enable "rewrite logging". Take a look into the documentation. It is of excellent quality: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append %f to your LogFormat. This will show you the final filesystem path, which is more concise than looking at mod_rewrite tracing.